# dateinterval::format enforcing leading zeros on month day

Tags: php, datetime

I'm running a date validation in PHP:

```
public function isValidDate($date) {
    $valid = false;
    $valid_formats = array(
        'Y-m-d',
        'm-d-Y',
        'Y/m/d',
        'm/d/Y'
    );
    foreach ($valid_formats as $format) {
        if (!$valid) {
            $d = \DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
            $valid = $d && $d->format($format) == $date;
        }
    }
    return $valid;
}
```

What's odd is that if the format is m/d/Y, and I pass 1/1/2016 to it, it is false, because when I run $d->format(m/d/Y), I get a result of 01/01/2016.

Any ideas on why it is enforcing the leading zeros?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because you have not defined a valid format that matches a date with only one character day and month fields

```
function isValidDate($date) {
    $valid = false;
    $valid_formats = array(
        'Y-m-d',
        'm-d-Y',
        'Y/m/d',
        'm/d/Y',
        'j/n/Y',        // <- NEW day/month 1/1
        'n/j/Y'         // <- NEW month/day 1/1
    );
    foreach ($valid_formats as $format) {
        if (!$valid) {
            $d = \DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
            $valid = $d && $d->format($format) == $date;
        }
    }
    return $valid;
}

echo isValidDate('1/1/2016') ? 'VALID' : 'INVALID';
```

There may be others you need to add as well!

Comment: Just figured that out. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer, from W3Schools.

It seems the official documentation is missing some format options:

```
d - Day of the month; with leading zeros
j - Day of the month; without leading zeros

m - Month (01-12)
n - Month (1-12)
```

'j' and 'n' are missing from http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php